# how can i modify the response of a sequelize request?

Tags: javascript, postgresql, sequelize.js

i am trying to modify the response object of a sequelize request, but i can't seem to understand how to do this correctly. here is the code :

```js
  async updateCardPosition(req,res) {
    const oldPosition = Number(req.params.oldposition);
    const newPosition = Number(req.params.newposition);
    const listId = Number(req.body.listId);
   
    try {
      const card = await Card.findOne({where :{ 
        position : oldPosition,
        list_id:listId
      }});

      let cardToUpdate = JSON.stringify(card)
      cardToUpdate.position = newPosition;

      res.send(cardToUpdate);
    }catch (error) {
      res.status(500).send(error);
    }
  }
}
```

so the response is sent correctly, through postman i get a status of 200, and the response object is visible on the screen, but the "position" property hasn't changed. Though i made sure that the value of "newPosition" was valid...

any idea ?
thank you !

Comment: You need to use `card.position = newPosition`, and *before* you stringify it. However stringifying it is not necessary in the first place, in fact you shouldn't and do `res.json(card);` instead. Stringifying changes an object into a JSON *string*. Also note that you aren't saving the modified card to the DB, and `cardToUpdate` seems like a weird choice for that variable, given that it's supposed to be a stringified version of an already updated card.

Comment: yes thank you ! well the stringify thing was a mistake, but yes after that i saving the modified card, it all works well now !